# Getting a search parameter from HTML to Python Flask Function

Tags: python, html, ajax, python-twitter

pretty new to flask and ajax and was wondering if i could get some help. I am using python-twitter and want to be able to type in a search parameter that will search twitter for the requested word/words.

I have tried multiple solutions and both my friend and i can't see where it is going wrong. I can see the search variable being stored in ajax through a console.log but i can't get it to transfer that variable over to the twitter function that will search for the variable.

Here is my ajax:

```
            $('#form').on('submit', function(e){
                var search = $('#search').val();
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/twitter',
                    data: {'search': search},
                    method: 'Get',
                    success: function(result) {
                        // twit(data)
                        console.log(search)
                    }
                });
            });
```

And my Twit() As requested

```
@app.route('/twitter', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def twit():

    tempo =  request.form['search']
    searched = "Yes"
    searched = request.args.get('search1')
    # searched = request.form.get('number')
    print(searched, file=sys.stderr)

    api = twitter.Api(\
            consumer_key='TWVxfrliliibQxjNWz4tAlDIj',
            consumer_secret='QK2IBqNorysgD3quaBJVCMDdMApOpo5fW5g6Pl4Di97ToRjsGy',
            access_token_key='3011394611-QmeEQ5yaL6OJTOmqemXV3eS0DpE09P0sy64XhnL',
            access_token_secret='tEMygLkKBDwfVepHAg7G9BI7N8VQJM7U9KKefpV40jUq1'
        )
    count = "10"
    data = api.GetSearch(
    raw_query=  'q='+str(searched)+'&'
                'count='+str(count)+'&'
                'lang=en&'
                'tweet_mode=extended&'
                #'geocode=51.4027029,-0.3040634,10mi' #kington
    )

    print(data)
    for i in data:
        print('---------------------------')
        if hasattr(i, 'retweeted_status'):
            print(i.user.name + ': ' +  i.full_text)
        else:
            print(i.user.name + ': ' +  i.retweeted_status.full_text)

    return(render_template('Twitter.html', d=data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is the form

```
                    <form method="get" id="form">
                            <label for="search">Enter Search Parameter : </label>
                            <input type="text" id="search" name="search" autofocus autocomplete="off">
                            <button>Post</button>
                    </form>
```

The page should be updated using the searched for term.

Apologies if there is a very obvious mistake

Comment: Hi Maximus, please add related backend code for the "Twitter" method and front-end related code to your `<form id="form">` (at least I assume it is a form element you are trying add an event listener to).

Comment: Sorry, there we go

Comment: Yeah the form is from another solution with ajax

Comment: One thing to note is that you are sending the Ajax request as a `GET` request but are looking for the parameter in the form data. GET requests do not have a body.

Comment: So i should change it to Post?

Comment: I am not very familiar with Python but maybe try to change it to a POST method and see what value your parameters contain.

Comment: It still contains the same output as if it were GET